# Displaying current user's data to other user

Tags: java, android, database, parsing

My app is a blood donation app in which first we get the info from users, maintain it into Parse.com database. then displaying that data into 2 different listviews as for donor and acceptor, 
Now when the user click on the any one user from the list, that current user's data is sent to the user mentioned in that list with a notification. requested user get the notification with an activity, now this is where is problem is coming, I'm unable to get that data displayed on that activity to the user being requested.

```
      //This is the reciver class that's opening that acitivty to the requested user


    private static final String TAG = "Receiver";
      @Override
     public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


      try {
            ParseObject perseonj = new ParseObject(arg1.getExtras().getString(
                    "com.parse.Data"));

            String event_id = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();

            Intent eventIntent = new Intent(arg0, ShowPopUp.class);
            eventIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           eventIntent.putExtra("id", event_id);

           String struser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername().toString();
           String bg = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("BloodGroup").toString();


            Intent i = new Intent();
               i.putExtra("idd", struser.toString());
              i.putExtra("bg", bg.toString());  

            arg0.getApplicationContext().startActivity(eventIntent);
            System.out.println(event_id);

        } catch (android.net.ParseException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "PARSEException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

       }

       }

    // This is the acitivty which actually displays the data


    public class ShowPopUp extends Activity implements OnClickListener
        {
     @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("COPAN");
        setContentView(R.layout.popupdialog);


       TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      final String current = getIntent().getExtras().getString("idd");
     tv.setText(current);

      TextView vtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
      final String currentt = getIntent().getExtras().getString("bg");
     vtv.setText(currentt); 

         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `intent.getStringExtra("bg");` you are saving the data in the intent. when you are calling `intent.getExtras()` you are getting back the `Bundle` of that intent

```
final String currentt = getIntent().getString("bg");
```

Also notice that there is no reason to call `toString` on a string object...

---  EDIT ----

```
 eventIntent.putExtra("idd", struser.toString());
 eventIntent.putExtra("bg", bg.toString());
```

instead of using new `Intent i` which you are not setting and passing...

Comment: I tried this but its displaying nothing, blank text fields !

Comment: You are getting nothing because you are not setting the data on the right Intent. update code

Comment: It's displaying my own data to me :| i.e the one in list is receiving its own data rather then the data of the one who requested him

Comment: check your current user if it was selected and updated as supposed to. but you have succeeded to send the data to the new activity which was the point of your question no? (-:

Comment: Yup thanks for that :) but the correct one :| and yes as i'm the current user but the user receiving that will be the current user over there too right? then how can i handle this?

Comment: please consider to accept my answer if i've helped you. get the data from the adapter (if you are using list) using the position of the list.

Comment: just did! ok got it. but can you tell me if i can do that through broadcasting receiver???

Comment: broadcast receivers are for communications between apps on the same device. is this what you want?